# Is this the correct jQuery to remove a <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html:

```
<div id="popups">
    <div id="createform">
        <div id="createformInside">
            <input type="text" id="testTitle" size="20">
            <input type="text" id="testSubj">
            <span id="testOptions">More Options</span>
            <br/>
            <textarea id="testContent" ></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Save Test" id="saveBttn">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The below jQuery is supposed to remove everything inside of the popups `<div>` when the save button is pushed. For some reason it is not. Any idea why not?

```
$('#saveBttn').click( function() {//if the save button on the create test form is clicked...
    $('#createform').remove();//gets rid of the create test form
})
```

Comment: This works for me. What, if anything, happens when you hit the button?

Comment: You should make sure your `input` elements (and friends) are descendants of a `form` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

Just tested your sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/bFXKP/

Works fine from that demo so there could be something else you're missing.

Comment: test to see if the click event is binding properlly to the button (throw in a console.log/alert). Other than that see if you can do some other modification to the #createform div (display: none)

Comment: ok, I tried both of those and they did not work. its strange that none of this is logging as console errors.

Comment: console.log($) or console.log(jQuery) make sure there's no problem there. Also try pasting that code into your console and running it. Could be some problem trying to execute the whole thing.

Comment: what are those supposed to return? They returned this for me: function (i,r){return new b.fn.init(i,r)}
undefined

Comment: ...if the latter returned undefined, it means you either neglected to load jQuery, or you neglected to wrap the `click` function in a document ready closure.

Comment: ok, I think I did both of those. i just put the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/ggJ4d/ . Hopefully that helps.

Comment: don't worry about it actually. I needed to use .delegate() or .live()

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the `<input>` fields in a `<form>` tag. Otherwise, the DOM doesn't have a way to know what to do with the inputs, or which inputs to 'submit' with the button.

Additionally, its generally considered better practice to have the event bind to the `<form>` tag's ID using `submit()`, rather than `click()`, since `submit()` will catch non-clicked submissions (ie, using the keyboard, enter button, etc).

---

EDIT: if `console.log(jQuery)` returns undefined, that means it means you either neglected to load jQuery, or you neglected to wrap the click function in a document ready closure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to stop multiple submissions to your form?

If so...

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    $(this).find('input[type=submit], button[type!=button]').attr({ disabled: 'disabled' });
});
```

Comment: no, I'm not. I am just trying to hide a form that is displayed on top of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me. Are you having some sort of problem with this code or were you just asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

$('#createform').css('display','none');

Comment: yeah, I originally used that, but that gets the DOM all messy when you are doing it all over the place. This is just a little piece of a completely ajax web app.